# Обработка коллекций React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, коллекции

**Есть компонент**

`<Definitions data={definitions} />`

Который принимает в props объект

```
const definitions = [
  { dt: 'one', dd: 'two' },
  { dt: 'another term', dd: 'another description' },
];
```

**Должно отрендерится**

```
<dl>
  <dt>one</dt>
  <dd>two</dd>
  <dt>another term</dt>
  <dd>another description</dd>
</dl>
```

Как получить коллекцию и отрендерить я понял, но как сделать вложенность не могу сообразить.
Выбрасывает ошибку

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): `<dd>` cannot appear as a descendant of `<dt>`.

**Вот что получилось написать:**

```
export default class Definitions extends Component {


  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return <dl>
      {data.map((item, index) => <dt key={index}>{item.dt}
      </dt>)}
    </dl>
  }
}
```

Comment: используйте [фрагменты](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments)

Comment: используйте [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: @return вот в теории было про фрагменты <></> но я не понял как тут их применить

Comment: Еще раз убедился, что проще зайти в документацию, чем искать ответ в кастрированной теории курса. Примного благодарен)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае нужно воспользоваться `React.Fragment`, как контейнером в котором выводятся два соседних элемента

```js
function Definitions({data}){
    return (<dl>
      {
        data.map((item, index) => <React.Fragment key={index}>
          <dt>{item.dt}</dt>
          <dd>{item.dd}</dd>
        </React.Fragment>)
      }
    </dl>)
}

function App(){
  const definitions = [ { dt: 'one', dd: 'two' }, { dt: 'another term', dd: 'another description' } ]; 
  return <Definitions data={definitions} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже разобрался. Комментарии помогли)